# Is there a VS Code shortcut to edit the current global "settings.json" file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I frequently have to edit my global settings.json, but not frequently enough to be able to use the open recent menu in VS Code.

Is there a key binding or single button I can press that opens my current settings.json in the current VS Code window? It's irritating to have to keep navigating to `/Users/ME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json` every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by default but, if you open up `File | Preferences | Keyboard Shortcuts` and search for `JSON`, you'll find there's a `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` item that you can assign a shortcut to.

I've set mine to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to make it similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, the workbench setting editor.

You can, of course, also store this in your global `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "alt+,",
    "command": "workbench.action.openSettingsJson"
}
```

Comment: You can also overwrite the default settings shortcut, which I do since the settings editor is so bad. On Mac that looks like `{ "key": "cmd-,", "command": "workbench.action.openSettingsJson" },`